# Rendering user profile page in MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, meteor, routes, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to create a page for users so that when they are logged in they can see the content they've uploaded onto the site. I can't seem to get the page to render. I've searched all over, but can't seem to find anything. Any ideas of where I'm going wrong?

```
from my publication.js file

Meteor.publish('myTickets', function() {
  var currentUserId = this.userId;
  return Tickets.find({
    createdBy: currentUserId
  })
});

from the router.js

Router.route('/users/:_id', {
  name: 'userPage',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('myTickets');
  },
  data: function() {
    return Tickets.find({
      userId: this.userId
    })
  }
});

userpage.js

Template.userPage.helpers({
  tickets: function() {
    var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
    return Tickets.find({
      createdBy: currentUserId
    }, {
      sort: {
        createdAt: -1
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: First, are you trying to display the information of a specific user, or only the current logged in user ? Seems you have a route defined as "Router.route('/users/:_id'", but you are never invoking the given "_id" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I asked you in a comment what you exactly wanted to do (you have a route with a parameter, but you are never using it), but anyway, I think I got your problem;

You are using `this.userId` to get your current user ID in your router, but your should use `Meteor.userId()` instead; `this.userId` can only be used in publish methods.

Comment: I'm trying to show the currently logged in users ticket uploads. I tried switching out `this.userId` with `Meteor.userId()`, but it had no effect. I even tried changing the route to something like `/mytickets` which will render a view but there is nothing there.